# Submit al seleccionar un checkbox

Tags: jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de poner el `<script>` de este código en una función del tipo `.click()` para que se envié el formulario cada vez que se pulsa el `checkbox` y así prescindir del `<input type="submit"/>` .
Lo que hace el formulario es comprobar si el `checkbox` está seleccionado o no y obtengo la respuesta del servidor usando **Ajax**.

El código que tengo actualmente es este:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Noticias varias</title>
        <style>
        #noticias li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-right: 30px;
        }
        #noticias li a {
            padding: 5px 10px;
            background-color: white;
            color: black;
                text-decoration: none;
        }
        #noticias li a:hover {
            background-color: rgb(255,153,0);
            color: white;
        }
        #contenidos_externos #noticia {
            margin-top: 10px;
            padding: 20px;
                border: 1px solid white;
        }
        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#login").submit(function(){

                var datosFormulario = $(this).serialize();
                $.get("login.php",datosFormulario, procesarDatos);
                return false;
            });
            function procesarDatos(datosDevueltos){
                if(datosDevueltos == "autorizado"){
                    $("#contenidos_externos").html('<p>Seleccionado</p>');
                }else{
                    $("#contenidos_externos").html('<p>No seleccionado</p>');
                }
            }


        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="cabecera">
            <p class="logo">Procesando respuesta del servidor</p>
        </div>
        <div class="contenido">
            <div class="principal">
                <form method="get" action="login.php" id="login">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label for="usuario">Usuario:</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="usuario" id="usuario">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <!-- <label for="contra">Contaseña: </label> -->
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <!-- <input type="text" name="contra" id="contra"> -->
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                                <input type="submit" name="boton" id="boton" value="Enviar" >
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
                <div id="contenidos_externos"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**PHP**

```
if(isset($_GET['usuario'])){
    $el_usuario = true;
}

if ($el_usuario ) {
    echo 'autorizado';
} else {
    echo 'fallo';
}
```

El resultado del código se puede ver [aquí](http://www.gmarsi.com/programacion/checkboxInputSubmit/login2.html). 
Lo que quiero hacer es lo mismo pero que informe si está seleccionado o no solamente, haciendo click en el `checkbox`

He intentado poner un `on.('click')` pero no funciona:

```
$("#usuario").on('click', function(){

    $("#login").submit(function(){
        var datosFormulario = $("#login").serialize();
        $.get("login.php",datosFormulario, procesarDatos);

        return false;
    });

    function procesarDatos(datosDevueltos){
        if(datosDevueltos == "autorizado"){
            $("#contenidos_externos").html('<p>Seleccionado</p>');
        }else{
            $("#contenidos_externos").html('<p>No seleccionado</p>');
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: @lois6b el ultimo trozo de código que he publicado en la pregunta lo he probado dentro del `ready` pero no me funciona, cuando hago click en el `checkbox` simplemente no hace nada. A lo que te refieres, es que dentro del `onClick`ponga ` $("#login").submit(function(){ //codigo actual });` y la funcion `procesarDatos()` la ponga fuera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es una funcion que se llame cuando el value del checkbox cambie.

Y en esa funcion hacer todo lo que quieres hacer antes del submit y despues llamar al submit del form con `$('#login').submit();` (quita el comentario del codigo para que lo haga, lo comenté para que no salga error al redirigir)

```js
function beforeSubmit() {

  console.log("serializando");
  console.log("cogiendo datos");

  //$('#login').submit();
  
  console.log("submited!");

}


$(function() {
  $('#usuario').on('change', function() {
    beforeSubmit();
    //alert("pulsado")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" action="login.php" id="login">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="usuario">Submit:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="usuario" id="usuario">
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</form>
```